# Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc replacement?

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, apc

APC is not supported starting from PHP 5.5 (replaced by Zend OPcache),
so `Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc` is not usable anymore.

Is there any easy alternative? (eg. `Zend_Cache_Backend_OPcache`?) besides `memcached`?

Answer (score 0):

You can install APCu, which implements just the userland caching features of APC. `Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc` will then work exactly as it did before.